# Expected sample proportion given known population proportion?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, sample

Taking all accounts on a website, 66% of users have uploaded a photo. I sample 21 users, what can I expect to find in the sample? I'm looking for an answer like "usually, between 10 and 18 users (in that sample) would have a photo".

Most of the examples I see make inferences about the population from the sample, but this goes the other way around.

I'm not sure if "confidence interval" is the right word to describe this.

I think I can use `dbinom` to find the probability of each count:

```
d <- data.frame(count=0:21, prob=dbinom(0:21, 21, 0.66))

ggplot(d, aes(count, prob)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=0:21)
```

[image: count vs prob]

but it's not a "range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the quantiles of the binomial distribution. For example, a range which would include the number of users with a photo 95% of the time can be constructed by taking the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles.

In R (first for 95% chance, then for 90% chance of containing number of users):

```
> qbinom(p = c(0.025, 0.975), prob = 0.66, size = 21)
[1] 10 18
> qbinom(p = c(0.05, 0.95), prob = 0.66, size = 21)
[1] 10 17
```

It won't be perfect because there's no guarantee that you'll get exact quantiles for a binomial, but that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the `binom.confint` function (and related) can only be used to infer from sample to a population? And not the other way around?

Comment: Yes. It's not really inference going from population to sample, but you are correct.